# A Kind Cryptogram

Tags: cipher

***I made a cryptogram! Here it is:***

RVNTD HETPNCXH QR VPH MHRV CYV YCJA VPNV MGV NBHN 51 QR RY NFNWQCX NCL ZBYLGTVQKH Q JYKH VPQR SHMRQVH MHVVHB VPNC IGYBN

***And here are your clues:***

C=N

Comment: (For future reference, you may want to read [Code Puzzles: What (Not) To Do?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1717) for some guidance on how to turn a cipher challenge into an interesting puzzle. You may benefit from looking around the site, and in particular checking out the high voted puzzles in the tags that appeal to you, to get a better sense of what kinds of puzzles work best here. Welcome to Puzzling (take the **[Tour]!**), and I hope all your puzzles see great success!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The decoded text is:

> STACK EXCHANGE IS THE BEST NOT ONLY THAT BUT AREA 51 IS SO AMAZING AND PRODUCTIVE I LOVE THIS WEBSITE BETTER THAN QUORA

It is "a kind cryptogram" because

> The message is complimenting this website.

Comment: You got it right, great job :)